# Spring 403 Error - Trying to secure backend with JWT tokens

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-authentication, jwt

All of my requests are coming back with 403 Forbidden responses. **The firebase tokens I'm sending are being validated successfully** so I'm not sure what step I'm missing in setting this up? I'm just trying to get a simple flow working where my endpoints must have valid firebase JWT token in the header(outside the excluded health endpoints).

Current steps:

1. Custom OncePerRequestFilter created and is being hit on the appropriate endpoints
2. Authorization header token is successfully validated
3. Authentication object is created as a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, tracking the firebase token and users UID in there.
4. SecurityContext is set with the new authentication object.
5. ????

Response: {
"timestamp": "2022-01-09T16:44:08.342+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Access Denied",
"path": "/v1/dev/overweight/service/user/register"
}

My health endpoints which are excluded from the authentication are able to successfully make calls as well.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path:''}")
    private String contextPath;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new FireBaseFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override //src: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(
                "http://localhost:8080",
                "http://localhost:3000"
        ).allowedMethods("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
 @Slf4j
 public class FireBaseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private List<String> skipUrls = Arrays.asList("/health/**");
    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authToken = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER).substring(7);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            Authentication auth = getAuthentication(authToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Authentication getAuthentication(String jwtToken) {
        FirebaseToken token = verifyFireBaseToken(jwtToken);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getUid(), token);
    }

  private FirebaseToken verifyFireBaseToken(String jwtToken) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jwtToken)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("idToken is blank");
        }
        try {
            return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(jwtToken, true);
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            this.logger.error("exception thrown verifying firebase token");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return skipUrls.stream().anyMatch(p -> new AntPathMatcher().match(p, request.getServletPath()));
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't write that your code is working, if you remove `.addFilterBefore(new FireBaseFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`. Then the problem is your custom filter. You are not authenticated: `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getUid(), token);` You have to use the other construtor with authorities.

Comment: @dur hey man that worked! Thanks so much for the help, apologies if I sounded rude. Really appreciate your help

Comment: i would still recommend that you instead use the built in jwt functionality of spring security and customize that instead of writing custom filters.

Comment: @Toerkumlare Can you give more reasoning as to why? I think this way should give me more control over what's happening and allow me to use the Firebase SDK for validating a token which would prevent a roundtrip API call to an authorization server. Further, I have yet to see a Firebase Auth example that doesn't follow this design approach.

Comment: why? because writing custom security is bad practice. Spring security provides jwt functionality for you not to write it yourself. Spring security jwt functionality is battle tested, and run i 100000 of applications, and reviewed by hundreds. One faulty piece of code, one poor implementation and your entire applications data may be compromised. Custom security solutions are bad practice, and what is the point of using a security framework, written by security framework experts when you dont intend to use it.

Comment: and just because "you havn't seen one" doesnt make it right. There is a lot of poor "blogs" out there that all use custom filters for functionality that already exists in spring security just because they didnt even take the time to read the spring securiy reference and look up existing functionality in spring security. This is also why we se application being compromised on a daily basis, because everyone is writing custom poor security solutions.

Comment: i can ask you, did you read the spring security reference documentation before asking here? did you read the entire chapter they have written on JWTs, on how to correctly implement the handling of them in spring security? as said there is an entire chapter on it, and people dont even take the time to read it https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Comment: @Toerktumlare I feel like you're blowing things out of proportion. I'm not rolling my own security here, I'm extending SpringSecurity filters that already exist, so everything is still within the SpringSecurity framework. All I'm doing is customizing how the JWT token is authenticated so as to use the FirebaseJDK. I suspect theirs a reason everyone goes this route, and reading the doc you sent versus how I'm doing it. Personally I think the latter makes more sense and gives me more control and visibility into what's happening.

Comment: No you are writing custom security logic, parsing headers manually, etc. The reason people go that route is because people dont even take the time to read the reference and instead ask on stack overflow and we need to help everyone that constantly do faulty implementations. Custom security is bad practice, this is a custom security solution. Hence bad practice.

Comment: @Toerktumlare okay, appreciate the feedback. I'll give the Spring way a shot and see what happens. Just wish their was some other examples out there using firebase for me to go off. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@dur solved in the comments. I needed to add some authorities for the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getUid(), token, );

I modified my method to:

```
private Authentication getAuthentication(String jwtToken) {
    FirebaseToken token = verifyFireBaseToken(jwtToken);
    this.logger.info("Token verified!");
    List<GrantedAuthority> authoritiesList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authoritiesList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getUid(), token, authoritiesList);
}
```

I think from here, the next steps will be to create a proper UserDetailsService for handling this properly.